# using a regular expression within ._contains(arr, val);

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array:

```
var myArray = ['1','3','3-4','4','4-8','5-8','9'];
```

I also have a variable who equals **4**

I would like to find any values in the array who matches the following conditions:

1. Equals 4
2. 4-*
3. *-4

so in the above example I would find 3-4, 4-8, 4

`_.contains(myArray, 4)` solves #1 but how would I use a regular expression to find #2 and #3 in the above list. Keeping in mind **4** would be a variable I would need to drop into the RegEx

Can you use RegExs in the `_.contains` I can't seem to find any examples

Thanks!

Comment: `array(` is PHP syntax, not JavaScript :-P

Comment: Sorry that was pseudo code and looks like it gave away my background!

Comment: I figured, that's why I fixed it in the question for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_.filter` instead to find the element(s) you want.

```
_.filter(myArray, function(x){
    return x.match(/^(\d-)?4(-\d)?$/) !== null;
});
```

Comment: second hyphen-digit pair was backwards. fixed!